# rewriting a thesis statement

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Our teacher said that this is an example of how to write a thesis statement in your words again.

**The thesis statement:** Making healthy food choices are not easy.

**Her example:** Making healthy food choices and eating well do not have to be difficult.

l think their meanings are a bit opposite . what do you think ?

Comment: They are certainly different. As you suggest they are not direct opposites either.

Comment: This was from a ***teacher**?* That "thesis statement" *Making healthy food choices **are** not easy* isn't even grammatically valid! Look for a different teacher!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica l have no opportunity like this. It doesn't matter how good my teacher is because  l love learning english on my own by searching so l'm kinda independent.

Comment: That's good then. Don't think too hard about why this teacher "rephrased" a statement into something that means almost the opposite. She's just not a good teacher, and/or doesn't know her subject very well.

Answer (score 1):

> Making healthy food choices are not easy.

That should be *is* not *are* as it is the making which is the subject not the choices. This is a very common mistake particularly in speech where the verb is made to agree with the nearby noun rather than the subject.

> Her example: Making healthy food choices and eating well do not have to be difficult.

I view this has having a single concept as subject so I would write *does* not *do* in the same way as I would say "Bacon and eggs is the best breakfast" but opinions on that might differ.

The two sentences could be put into some form of contrast, something may not be easy but equally it does not have to be difficult. Usually you would follow that with an example of how it could be made not difficult. So you could say:

> Making healthy choices is not easy but it does not have to be difficult if you follow the guidance in this helpful booklet.

That sentence would be possible but there must be many better ways to say it like:

> Making healthy choices is difficult but it can be made easier if you follow the guidance in this helpful booklet

Although not part of the original question *thesis statement* sounds unusual to me, *statement of the thesis* would sound better or even just drop the word *statement* as, in this sense, a thesis is a form of statement.

Comment: But we have a compound subject here . The simple subjects are “making” and “eating.” “Making healthy food choices” is one element of the compound subject. “Eating well” is the other. so it should be plural. maybe you're wrong for this part.

Comment: That is an interesting point. I viewed them as a single concept so needing a singular verb but I can see other writers might take your view.